# Speech Recognition Issue on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on an app that is trying to use Speech Recognition to enter text. I don't have a particular grammar, I just want to dump the spoken text into a text box on Windows Phone 8.1

So I'm using the Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition libraries.

My code is basically this

```
SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer();
SpeechRecognitionResult result = await sr.RecognizeAsync();
if(result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.High || result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Medium)
    txtBox.Text = result.Text;
else
    txtBox.Text = "Huh?";

sr.Close()
```

I'm getting an error when I press the button to start the voice recognition: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

I've done some searching but the big results seem to be about some issues with ASP.NET years ago.

Anybody done some simple Speech Recognition for Windows Phone that can point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**
I eventually found the answer. Even though there are no additional constraints you need still need to compile the defaults.

```
sr.CompileConstraintsAsync();
```

And then you can do the

```
sr.RecognizeAsync()
```

function.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight? I'm not seeing the Close() method on SpeechRecognizer.

Comment: No, its Windows Store App. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizer.aspx

Comment: @TimFelty You should make your update the answer, cause it is the answer here. (more rep that way too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer. Even though there are no additional constraints you need still need to compile the defaults.

`sr.CompileConstraintsAsync();`

And then you can do the

`sr.RecognizeAsync()`

function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the microphone function in your app manifest?

Comment: I'm traveling for the holiday so I can't double check, but I'm pretty sure I did check that.